# Quick action opens automator

Tags: finder, automator

I have created a "Quick Action" workflow that copies a specified file to a new directory and doesn't require any input:
[image]

I added it to the quick panel in finder for the fast access but each time I use it opens the Automator app.

I've solved the issue by converting it to the application but it seems to me there should be a way to use quick actions properly.

As properly I mean: by clicking on the saved quick action, that I added to the panel in Finder, it performs all the steps without opening the Automator app each time.

Comment: Woah - that makes it super clear. You want this to run start to finish and not see Automator app. Basically save that as an app or a service? I didn't get what the "quick panel" means. I'll try an answer - hopefully it's what you seek but even if it's wrong it will help someone else getting a better answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your workflow receives No input in any application. Quick Actions are designed to run only on the type of file (or other object) that is currently selected. So I'm surprised that it shows up at all. Presumably Automator opens it because it "no input" is the default of an empty or unfinished workflow.

As your workflow doesn't require an input, (i.e. any given file as an argument), but just copies a specific file, then an application is a better choice.